# A proper place for SQL Alchemy's engine global

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, environment-variables, env-file

I'm new to the concept of using [a global variable](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) to spawn new DB Sessions. I want to import `settings.py` file into `manage.py` to call method that loads environment variables using the `.env` helper library `dotenv`. However, since the variables are not yet initialized in the moment of `settings.py` import into manage.py (the `.env` filename is yet to be read from `sys.argv`), the engine construction line cannot stay "in plain sight" (unindented). I wonder if `settings.py` are the right place for such a global variable? I'm used to `settings.py` only containing dictionaries of basic types, no objects or classes.
Right now `init_db_globs` looks like this.

```
# set the default db .env file name
def init_db_globs(db_name='db', env_file_name='.env'):
    # refer to global vars
    global engine, session
    # connection string template
    template_uri = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    # load env vars
    load_dotenv(env_file_name)
    # load database parameters from env vars
    dbs = {
        'db': {
            # 'var': os.getenv('DB_VAR'),
        },
        'db_test': {
            # 'var': os.getenv('DB_VAR_TEST'),
        }
    }
    uri = template_uri.format(db['user'],db['password'],db['host'],db['port'],db['name'])
    engine = create_engine(uri, params_list)
    # create a configured "Session" class
    Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    # init global session
    session = Session()

# create global vars
session = None
engine = None
```

How should this be improved?

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but you'll want to create sessions when you need them from a global sessionmaker, and not as a global session. [SQLAlchemy FAQ](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions).